# Orbeon forms Scrollable Check box validation

Tags: orbeon

I have created a 'Scrollable Check box' in Orbeon 4.8. The check box contains label as string and Value as Integer.How to validation the check box?.

**If user select(checked) the more then 3 options then it throw an error and form should not be save.If user select(checked) the less then 3 options or none then form should be save.**

Some one help me how to validate 'Scrollable Check box' above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a validation formula as follows:

```
count(xxf:split(.)) le 3
```

This tokenizes the space-separated values selected by the checkbox. If you count the tokens, you find the number of selected checkboxes. Then this makes sure the number of tokens is lower than or equal to 3.

I also added this to the [list of examples](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Builder-~-Formulas-~-Examples#constraint-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes).